# "advert" and "adverse": same etymoloty but unrelated meanings?

Tags: etymology

From Wiktionary and other similar sources like etymonline, the meanings of "advert" and "adverse" are:

> advert: turn attention
>
> adverse: Unfavorable; antagonistic in purpose or effect; hostile;
>   actively opposing one's interests or wishes; contrary to one's
>   welfare; acting against; working in an opposing direction.

"ad-" means "to", while "verse" and "vert" both mean "turn".

How shall I understand that they share same etymology but have unrelated meanings?

Comment: To put it in an overly simplified manner: one is turned towards you in a friendly way, the other is turned towards (against) you in a hostile way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they have different meanings is that although the stem *vertere* is constant both the prefix and suffixes alter the stem significantly. The prefix *ad-* in the two words is used in different senses and only means *toward* in *adverse*.

Thus in **advert** the prefix *ad-* is cognate with *a-* just having the effect of adding - leaving the meaning of the stem verb unchanged and in the present tense (**to turn**).

whereas in **adverse** the prefix *ad-* means *toward* (cognate with at) and the stem is formed from the past participle *verttus* changing to *versus* meaning **turned** - thus giving the (past participle) sense of *turned toward* or *opposed*.

This also explains why **advert** as discussed in the sense here is always a *verb* whereas **adverse** is always an *adjective* (i.e a noun modifier used as past participle).

Answer (score 1):

**adverse** :

adjective, comes from Old French *advers* (now *adverse*) = contrary, hostile, hurtful, injurious ; *advers* comes itself from Latin *advertere*

**advert to** :

verb, comes from Old French *advertir* (now *avertir* = to warn) = refer in speaking or writing ; *advertir* comes itself from the same Latin *advertere*

**advert** :

substantive, abbreviation for advertisement

advertisement comes from French *advertissement* (now *avertissement* = warning), with always the same Latin root

**The etymology is the same, meaning "turn towards" ; the French ... turned itself the meaning as turn against, or turn to show.**

You can turn towards somebody a board showing your goods for sale ... or a gun.

Answer (score -1):

The first advertisements were to warn against disease and plague and pestilence. Therefore the first advertisements were to warn against.

Comment: So keep that in mind next time you see an advertisement that it is actually warning you against that product historically

Comment: This answer would be substantially stronger if you supported its central assertion that "The first advertisements were to warn against disease and plague and pestilence" with a link to or citation from a reputable supporting reference work. Thanks!